# FHIR RESTful Adding multiple patients resources in a single call

Tags: rest, hl7-fhir

As the title says really.  I've been POSTing patient resources to FHIR via multiple calls and having the patient passed as xml.

I have hundreds of thousands of patients to add (as well as tons of other data).  I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to post this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a `Bundle`

https://www.hl7.org/FHIR/bundle.html

> Creating/updating/deleting a set of resources on a server as a single operation (including doing so as a single atomic transaction) (see Transactions)

Comment: Do you know which part of the RESTful API to send these to?   It might just be my eyes, but I can't see where it says which url/method to send it, just how to format the xml.  I've created an xml string which matches the example with multiple patients in it, but when I call POST to {{base}}/Patient, I get the response 'expected type of Patient, got type of bundle'?

Comment: @Andy: If you are talking about the RESTful API in the FHIR spec, check _batch/transaction_ section.

Comment: Batches are always posted at the base address of the server, not a specific type endpoint (like Patient), since the batch may contain resources of different types.